# Can a creature travel from the destination of the Teleportation Circle spell back to the source circle?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation

The *teleportation circle* spell description states that:

> You draw a 10-foot-diameter circle on the ground that links your location to a permanent teleportation circle whose sigil sequence you know and that is on the same plane of existence. A portal opens in the circle and remains open until the end of your next turn. Any creature that enters the portal instantly appears within 5 feet of the destination or in the nearest unoccupied space.

If the creature casting the spell and a creature next to the permanent teleportation circle are in constant communication with each other (sending stones for example), would the creature at the permanent teleportation circle be able to ride the portal backwards to the caster's location?

If not, besides *gate*, are there any other means of accomplishing something like this on the same plane of existence?

Comment: The quote in your post doesn't match the [official spell description](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/teleportation-circle). Please check the actual spell description and see if that clears up your confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Where did you get that spell description?

https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/teleportation-circle

> As you cast the spell, you draw a 10-foot-diameter circle on the ground inscribed with sigils that link your location to a permanent teleportation circle of your choice whose sigil sequence you know and that is on the same plane of existence as you. A shimmering portal opens *within the circle you drew* and remains open until the end of your next turn.

Comment: Yeah, I checked again and the current language of the spell does specify which circle has the portal.

Comment: It appears that the Teleportation Circle description they used was one from a fan-made wiki (it's not dandwiki). I don't know if it's an infringing site, so I shouldn't link it here. Nevertheless, it's not an official source.

Comment: Teleportation circle is part of the SRD, which isn't too heavily regulated.

Comment: @Axoren: It is indeed an infringing site; it includes non-SRD content as well. They intentionally reword things in a futile attempt to avoid getting taken down by WotC.

Comment: Er, if it's reworded, there's nothing to take down...!? The descriptive content\art of a game can be copyrighted, but the system cannot; that's what a patent is for, & those don't restrict publication of a design, only sale of it. I could be wrong? (I don't think I am; this has long been the only thing between many fansites & takedown...)

Comment: @ProphetZarquon can Wizards of the Coast demand a website remove a plagiarized section of their book that they sell? Yes. In much the same way JK Rowling can step in if a site has the entire harry potter series text. Books like the Players Handbook are protected by copyrights.

If you can read a site and not have to purchase the book from WotC or one of its sellers like DNDBeyond, then the site is violating copyright.

Comment: @MilesBedinger If it's paraphrased, you'll still need to buy the books, because the spells, 'Feats' & other traits function based on precise wording; a design intent similar to the wording of legal documents. Check again: Specific wording is protected by copyright; concepts & systems are not. If the wording used on a fan site *is* substantively different than the published wording, it's not infringing. This is not my opinion; it's why the majority of fan sites have been able to exist.

Answer (score 1):

### No, you can't. The circle is a one-way portal.

The portal opens at the circle you drew, and transports creatures to the other circle. It makes no provision for them to get back.